# All possible passwords with 9 characters and limitations.

Tags: combinations

Limitations are: no repetitions, all lowercase(26) and must be in ascending order.

Now the main problem here is ascending order, so if you know any good resources that tackle this problem I would be very grateful. Also sorry if the questions has been asked, but I didn't find it :(

Comment: Stars and bars.  Google it.  Basically the are 18 options for the first letter. If the first letter is k, there are  19-k options for the second, for rge third there are 20 - k - j and so on.  If you do sumations of sumations you'll get somewhere.

Comment: Oops.  The answers are better than my cooment.  Maybe I'll work out if my comment was wrong, or correct but harder than nescessary.

Answer (score 1):

To choose such a password you have to choose $9$ letters from the set of $26$. You don't have to choose their order, because it is already chosen. The answer is
$$\binom{26}9$$

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no repetitions, we are simply choosing 9 distinct letters of the 26. Now, once we pick those 9, there is only one way to arrange them in ascending order, so the answer is just ${26}\choose{9}$.